# Getting date only

Tags: vb.net

I want to get today's date.  Using Now(), I get both date and time but I need date only.
How to get it?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [**`System.DateTime.Today`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx). Some additional notes:

- While you're only interested in the date, you still get a [`System.DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) object. That is, there still *is* a time portion in the returned value, but it's left blank (all zeroes).

  It's important to remember this when you compare dates. If you want to compare two dates, and you've fetched one date via `DateTime.Today` and another date via `DateTime.Now`, then these two dates will not be equal — precisely because one has the time set and the other doesn't.
- In VB.NET, the `Date` keyword is equivalent to the `System.DateTime` type. So you can write:

  ```
  Date.Today
  ```

  **P.S.:** It just occurred to me that it might be a good idea to write `Date.Today`, but `DateTime.Now`, in order to make it even more explicit that the former property only returns the date portion, while the latter returns both a date and time portion.

Comment: Since Today returns the time portion with all zeroes, how is that different from a meaning of midnight (12:00 AM)?

Comment: @kajaco: There is no difference. The time portion of `DateTime` is not nullable, so you have to decide yourself whether it is relevant or whether it should be ignored.

Comment: Pretty useless, since it isn't the same date across the globe and there's no way to specify a time zone.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `DateTime.Today` method for just the current date.

This returns a `DateTime` object, just like `DateTime.Now`, but it's time portion is always set to 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
    Imports System

Public Class MainClass

    Shared Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
       Dim currentTime as System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
       Console.WriteLine("currentTime Year :" & currentTime.Year)
       Console.WriteLine("currentTime Month:" &  currentTime.Month)
       Console.WriteLine("currentTime Date:" & currentTime.Date)
       Console.WriteLine("currentTime Hour:" & currentTime.Hour)
       Console.WriteLine("currentTime Minute:" & currentTime.Minute)
       Console.WriteLine("currentTime Second:" & currentTime.Second)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'try the simple way................... enjoy..  
    Imports System  -general declaration part
Private Sub Show_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim currentdate As System.DateTime
            Dim currenttime As System.DateTime
            Dim currentDateTime As System.DateTime
            currentdate = DateAndTime.Today
            currenttime = DateAndTime.TimeOfDay
            currentDateTime = DateAndTime.Now

            MsgBox(currentdate)
            MsgBox(currenttime)
            MsgBox(currentDateTime)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler this way

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim GDate As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GDate = Today
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you will have to retrieve you will get it
and can convert into again date format later also

```
Dim dt1 As String = Today
Dim time1 As String = TimeOfDay

msgbox(dt1)
msgbox(time1)
```